# Не срабатывает focus на div

Tags: html, css, hover, focus

Не работает `:focus` не могу понять почему,с `:active` и `:hover` все хорошо, что не так?

CSS:

```
.icons{
   display: block;
   width: 104px;
   height: 92px;
   margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 2px;
   background-color: rgb(251, 251, 251);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(20, 20, 21, 0.14);
}

.icons:focus{
   border-radius: 2px;
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 36px 0px rgba(20, 20, 21, 0.2); 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="title">
    <div class="serviceIcon">
        <div class="icons">
            <img src="img\service\diagramm.png" alt="diagramm">
        </div>
        <div class="icons">
            <img src="img\service\tech.png" alt="tech">
        </div>
        <div class="icons">
            <img src="img\service\loope.png" alt="loope">
        </div>
        <div class="icons">
            <img src="img\service\diagramm.png" alt="diagramm">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="serviceContent">

    </div>
    <div class="serviceImage">
        <img src="img\apple-watch-mockup.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Псевдокласс `:focus` определяет стиль для элемента получающего фокус. Например, им может быть текстовое поле формы, в которое устанавливается курсор. Он и работает, в основном, на элементах формы (textarea, input и т. п.). Что бы на `div` или на другие элементы работал `:focus`, нужно указать `tabindex`:

```css
div {width:200px;height:50px;background-color:grey}
div:focus {background-color: green}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0"></div>
```

Comment: или любой валидный tabindex собственно, не обязательно 0

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, просто, смотрел в старых браузерах, там работает только если `tablindex` будет именно `0`

Comment: в старых браузерах, это где? Имена, явки, пароли

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, explorer и safari для windows (safari для windows только древнейший есть)

Comment: Эксплорер - какой? Их много и все разные. Сафари для виндоус в здравом уме никто не поддерживает, полагаться на него - не стоит.

Comment: говорите для форм в основном. а если там всякие менюшки? Или вот в моем случае, "кнопки", от выбора которой, справа от них показывается разный текст.. тобишь надо чтоб она была в фокусе дабы человек видел с какого " раздела" он читает.

Comment: @adckiykpolb, да, по умолчанию, для форм. Добавьте tabindex чтобы сказать браузеру что этот элемент можно фокусить, и оно - заработает.

Comment: И если не сложно, был бы благодарен за разьяснение, каким образом приоритет фокуса посредством кнопки tab влияет на то будет ли div браться в фокус или нет...

Comment: @adckiykpolb, так решили разработчики браузерных движков (по крайней мере двух из большой тройки-четверки), поэтому и влияет. В спеке не уверен что это где-то написано, вероятно нигде. Буду рад если кто-то кинет в меня строчкой спеки и докажет что я ошибаюсь.

Comment: В общем, запомнить как данность ;D

Comment: @adckiykpolb, да, так и есть. Ну и учитывать что всякие контролы форм, и кажется ссылки (но не уверен) должны работать и без этого костыля.

Comment: Короче я ошибался, в спеке оно есть: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute, но насколько я понимаю как робкое предложение, а не как требование, поэтому часть браузеров это игнорят.